# Can't create object in the controller Yii2

Tags: yii2

I am trying to create on instance of `ProductReview` which has CRUD and model and database table but I get an empty object. I tried with other models but they all work as expected. Can you give me advice?

This is what I have in my controller:

```
$review = new ProductReview();
        var_dump($review);die;
```

which returns:

```
object(backend\modules\products\models\ProductReview)#322 (8) { ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(0) { } ["_oldAttributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> NULL ["_related":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(0) { } ["_errors":"yii\base\Model":private]=> NULL ["_validators":"yii\base\Model":private]=> NULL ["_scenario":"yii\base\Model":private]=> string(7) "default" ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } }
```

And because of that I get an error in my `ActiveForm` which is:

> Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on string

Why does that happen and why is it happening only with `ProductReview`? Do you guys have a clue? Thank you!

**EDIT**
Model:

```
 <?php
namespace backend\modules\products\models;

use Yii;
use backend\modules\products\models\Product;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "product_review".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $product_id
 * @property integer $user_id
 * @property integer $active
 * @property string $language
 * @property string $names
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $title
 * @property string $review
 * @property integer $rating
 * @property string $dt
 */
class ProductReview extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'product_review';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['product_id', 'language', 'names', 'review', 'rating'], 'required'],
            [['product_id', 'user_id', 'active', 'rating', 'is_home', 'status'], 'integer'],
            [['review'], 'string'],
            [['dt'], 'safe'],
            [['language'], 'string', 'max' => 10],
            [['names', 'title'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['email'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
            'product_id' => Yii::t('app', 'Product'),
            'user_id' => Yii::t('app', 'Customer'),
            'active' => Yii::t('app', 'Active'),
            'language' => Yii::t('app', 'Language'),
            'names' => Yii::t('app', 'Names'),
            'email' => Yii::t('app', 'Email'),
            'title' => Yii::t('app', 'Title'),
            'review' => Yii::t('app', 'Review'),
            'rating' => Yii::t('app', 'Rating'),
            'dt' => Yii::t('app', 'Date'),
            'is_home' => Yii::t('app', 'home'),
        ];
    }
    
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
    }
    
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Product::className(), ['id' => 'product_id']);
    }
    
    public function changeActiveForm() {
        $active = "";
        if ($this->active == 1) {
            $active = 'checked="checked"';
        }
        return '<label class="switchery switchery-default taCenter">
                <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" data-color="#99d683" data-secondary-color="#f96262" value="1" id="check_' . $this->id . '" name="field_types" class="legend-switch" ' . $active . ' onchange="changeStatusActive(' . $this->id . ', \'product-review\');"></input>
                <label data-off="'.Yii::t('app', 'Не').'" data-on="'.Yii::t('app', 'Да').'" for="check_' . $this->id . '"></label>
                <span></span>
            </label>';
    }
    
    public function changeHome() {
        $active = "";
        if ($this->is_home == 1) {
            $active = 'checked="checked"';
        }
        return '<label class="switchery switchery-default taCenter">
                <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" data-color="#99d683" data-secondary-color="#f96262" value="1" id="checkH_' . $this->id . '" name="field_types" class="legend-switch" ' . $active . ' onchange="changeHome(' . $this->id . ', \'product-review\');"></input>
                <label data-off="'.Yii::t('app', 'Не').'" data-on="'.Yii::t('app', 'Да').'" for="checkH_' . $this->id . '"></label>
                <span></span>
            </label>';
    }
    
    public function changeStatus() {
        $active = "";
        if ($this->status == 1) {
            $active = 'checked="checked"';
        }
        return '<label class="switchery switchery-default taCenter">
                <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" data-color="#99d683" data-secondary-color="#f96262" value="1" id="checkS_' . $this->id . '" name="field_types" class="legend-switch" ' . $active . ' onchange="changeStatus(' . $this->id . ', \'product-review\');"></input>
                <label data-off="'.Yii::t('app', 'Не').'" data-on="'.Yii::t('app', 'Да').'" for="checkS_' . $this->id . '"></label>
                <span></span>
            </label>';
    }
    
    public function getUserList() { // could be a static func as well
        $users = User::find()->all();
        $arrayUsers = array();
        if($users){
            foreach($users as $user){
                $arrayUsers[$user->id] = $user->username;
            }
        }
        return $arrayUsers;
    }
    
    public function getProductList() { // could be a static func as well
        $products = Product::find()->all();
        $arrayProducts = array();
        if($products){
            foreach($products as $product){
                $arrayProducts[$product->id] = $product->title;
            }
        }
        return $arrayProducts;
    }
    
    public function showRating() {
        $rating = $this->rating;
        $ratingHTML = '';
        $ratingHTML .= '<ul class="ratingList">';
        $ratingHTML .= ($rating >= 1) ? '<li class="active">': '<li>';
        $ratingHTML .= '<i class="fa fa-star-o empty tr_all_hover"></i>';
        $ratingHTML .= '<i class="fa fa-star active tr_all_hover"></i>';
        $ratingHTML .= '</li>';
        $ratingHTML .= ($rating >= 2) ? '<li class="active">': '<li>';
        $ratingHTML .= '<i class="fa fa-star-o empty tr_all_hover"></i>';
        $ratingHTML .= '<i class="fa fa-star active tr_all_hover"></i>';
        $ratingHTML .= '</li>';
        $ratingHTML .= ($rating >= 3) ? '<li class="active">': '<li>';
        $ratingHTML .= '<i class="fa fa-star-o empty tr_all_hover"></i>';
        $ratingHTML .= '<i class="fa fa-star active tr_all_hover"></i>';
        $ratingHTML .= '</li>';
        $ratingHTML .= ($rating >= 4) ? '<li class="active">': '<li>';
        $ratingHTML .= '<i class="fa fa-star-o empty tr_all_hover"></i>';
        $ratingHTML .= '<i class="fa fa-star active tr_all_hover"></i>';
        $ratingHTML .= '</li>';
        $ratingHTML .= ($rating >= 5) ? '<li class="active">': '<li>';
        $ratingHTML .= '<i class="fa fa-star-o empty tr_all_hover"></i>';
        $ratingHTML .= '<i class="fa fa-star active tr_all_hover"></i>';
        $ratingHTML .= '</li>';
        return $ratingHTML;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code for this model.

Comment: Yes, my bad. It is on now.

Comment: What is the exact name of the database table that model maps?

Comment: It is `product_review`.

Comment: This is weird. Try maybe to flush cache.

Comment: Man i found it ... afther my $review declaration i have another one with the same name in the controller which is :`$review = (strlen(OutData::showTXT($book->short_description)) > 500) ? mb_substr(strip_tags(OutData::showTXT($book->short_description)), 0, 500, "utf-8") . '...' : strip_tags(OutData::showTXT($book->short_description));` ... Thank you very much for your time man! You always answer first on my questions. Appreciate that realy!